# ActiveRecord Validation failed running seeds on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am on chapter 9 of ruby on rails tutorial and I have a problem on the last minute. Everything works normally on my page but not on heroku.
Here are the steps he said:

```
$ git push heroku
$ heroku pg:reset DATABASE
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
$ heroku run rake db:seed
$ heroku restart
```

when i run `rake db:seed`

```
Running rake db:seed on radiant-peak-3596... up, run.3507
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (4.6ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (8.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('example@hotmail.com') LIMIT 1
   (3.8ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/app/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

seed.rb

```
User.create!(name: "example user",
             email: "example@hotmail.com",
             password: "foobar",
             password_confirmation: "foobar",
             admin: true )

99.times do |n|
    name = Faker::Name.name
    email = "example-#{n+1}@aol.org"
    password = "password"
   User.create!(name: name,
                email: email, 
                password: password,
                password_confirmation: password)
end
```

I already installed the gem and it runs perfectly, but heroku is another case.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your seed.rb file look like? Are you actually using Faker as part of your seed generation? Seems like you're hardcoding the user `example@hotmail.com`. Doesn't seem like something faker would generate

Comment: @LeoCorrea hi! yes it hardcoding! it looks like this.
let me edit

Comment: I'm assuming your data is not being reset or you're running `rake db:seed` twice. That's the reason your seed is failing because you're attempting to create that hardcoded user twice and validations fail.

Comment: @LeoCorrea Hola leo! ya esta no se habia reseteado bien la base de datos! no se porque! pero ahora anda! mil gracias! como pongo que me lo solucionaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the database it's properly being reset. It seems that when running `rake db:seed` it's doing it against a database with a User already created which causes your validation error.

Answer (score 0):

You want to art the deputy to hold to crowd every college you are applying toâ€“in as numerous jurisdiction as you perhaps canâ€“plus being-possessed your synthesiss about yourself, staid among a propagate acumen of which academy you are talking to whereas you homespun that ancillarys.
[windows 8.1 key](http://serialkeygeneratorfree.com/serial-windows-8-1-product-key-crack-free-download/)